# Write-only properties with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my entity class, I'm trying to make a write-only field (gets ignored during serialization, but gets de-serialized normally).

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonSerialize(using=NullSerializer.class)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

This *almost* gives me what I want: the JSON contains the "password" field, but the value is always null. How do I remove the field entirely?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`@JsonIgnore`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) on just the *getter* `getPassword`, instead of using the `NullSerializer`. Then also use `@JsonProperty("password")` on the *setter*.

This should allow `password` to be de-serialized, but the JSON output of serialization won't include it.

> For example, a "getter" method that would otherwise denote a property (like, say, "getValue" to suggest property "value") to serialize, would be ignored and no such property would be output unless another annotation defines alternative method to use.

Comment: JsonIgnore would also prevent it from getting deserialized. This is not what I want.

Comment: sorry thought for sure I've only needed to `@JsonIgnore` the getter, but I just tested and I need to also add `@JsonProperty` to the getter. Maybe this has changed across versions, dunno. See edit.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one: `@JsonProperty` on the setter, and `@JsonIgnore` on the getter. Thank you very much.

Comment: This behavior depends on version: in 1.8 and before, one @JsonIgnore would be enough. But 1.9 unified property handling (to reduce duplication for common case), and you need 2 annotations for this "split" case.

Comment: @StaxMan thans for the clarification, I was sure that I'd only needed the `@JsonIgnore` in the past. Good to know if for when I update.

Answer (score 24):

You can set `access` value:

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

Comment: @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) along with @JSONCreator is not working