# Spring Data Rest: Different resource returned from received

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In Spring Data Rest, is it possible to return a different resource to a request, and receive a different resource object when reading from the request body?

An example when adding a user:

`{"username": "admin", "password": "123456"}`

An example when querying a user:

`{"username": "admin"}`

As you can see above, when someone adds a user, they would have to send the password, but I would like to not send the password when sending it as response.

Comment: Sound's like a duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872914/write-only-properties-with-jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add @JsonIgnore to the relevant property. That would always hide the password when the user object is marshalled.

```
public class user {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    private void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will prevent sending the password to the service.

Comment: Ah of course. You should however be able to put that on the getter though. I'll amend the example I put up.

Comment: Placing it on the getter still ignores the entire property.

Comment: The suggested solution is almost correct. See this one for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872914/write-only-properties-with-jackson