# @JsonIgnore field is not consuming data from Postman

Tags: java, json, spring, restful-url

I have used the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to prevent exposing the password to the user while sending user details to the user:

```
public class UserDto {

    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

}
```

Below is the response of user API:

```
{
 "username": "test12"
}
```

But while saving the new user when I am hitting the save API and send
below data, my controller method is consuming `null` password because of
@JsonIgnore and getting null pointer exception;

```
{
 "username": "test1225",
 "password": "admin"
}
```

Controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addAccount(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());

        userService.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);        
    }
```

Is there any way to ignore the Password parameter when returning
response to the user and not to ignore the password field value when
getting password parameter in request body in controller method?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're using a single DTO for two different purposes? Try separating them, things will become more straightforward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write-only properties with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872914/write-only-properties-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonView`s to specify which fields should be included during serialization/deserialization. Take a look at this blog post to learn about JsonViews - http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation.

For your issue, you can create a view called UserResponse.

```
public class UserResponse {
}
```

And annotate the fields of UserDto which you want to return with `@JsonView(UserResponse.class)`

```
public class UserDto {

    @JsonView(UserResponse.class)
    private String username;

    private String password;

}
```

And in your controller, add JsonView annotation on the return type.

```
public @JsonView(UserResponse.class) ResponseEntity<Void> addAccount(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
```